# How to create string for using variables inside string in shell-script

Tags: bash, shell

Hi My variable is not getting String using shell-script

I try to create string variable But getting Error :- "Missing }."

`log_handler_ws_async="<property name='path' value='"${domain.home}"/servers/"${weblogic.Name}"/logs/async.log'/>"`

When we use this variable. it's will get same string... we don't want value for this ${weblogic.Name}

echo $log_handler_ws_async

**expected output:-**

`"<property name='path' value='"${domain.home}"/servers/"${weblogic.Name}"/logs/async.log'/>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `read` builtin with heredoc:

```bash
read -r log_handler_ws_async <<-'EOF'
<property name='path' value='"${domain.home}"/servers/"${weblogic.Name}"/logs/async.log'/>
EOF

echo "$log_handler_ws_async"

<property name='path' value='"${domain.home}"/servers/"${weblogic.Name}"/logs/async.log'/>
```